# Combine columns from multiple files

Tags: r

I have written a code that should combine multiple files into one file by combining the second column in the input files. The first column is similar across input files.  However, it gives an error that I cannot understand.

```
files <- list.files(path = "/Rfam/",pattern='\\.sam')
```

My code

```
lst <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x,header=TRUE))
setNames(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='V1'),
                lst),c('ID', paste0('file',seq_along(files))) )
```

The error

```
> lst <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x,header=TRUE))
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput100G.sam': No such file or directory
```

My files:

```
> head(files)
[1] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput100G.sam"
[2] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput100R.sam"
[3] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput106G.sam"
[4] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput106R.sam"
[5] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput122G.sam"
[6] "Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput122R.sam"
> length(files)
[1] 96
```

Example of input

```
DMED7013:Rfam robinm$ head Rfam_Counts_combined_SplitRfam_Counts_combinedhtseq_Rfamoutput402R.sam
Seq_../trimmed/402R.tally.fasta __not_aligned
__too_low_aQual 3
mir-10 5
Y_RNA 4
__too_low_aQual 0
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned 1
mir-8 2
mir-671 3
mir-671 16
```

Comment: Could it be that your working directory is not set up correctly? You do `list.files` on the `/Rfam/` directory, but the file names in `files` are then read as being in your current working directory.

Comment: Add `full.names = TRUE` to your `list.files` call. At that point, the file names will start with `/Rfam/` (which is where they actually are)

Comment: It worked better, but I get: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Column1 has unique header